I have the same problem with expo 51.0.8. I tried this:
./gradlew assembleRelease

Configure project :expo

Using expo modules

expo-asset (10.0.6)
expo-constants (16.0.1)
expo-file-system (17.0.1)
expo-font (12.0.5)
expo-keep-awake (13.0.2)
expo-linear-gradient (13.0.2)
expo-modules-core (1.12.11)
expo-splash-screen (0.27.4)
expo-sqlite (14.0.3)
expo-system-ui (3.0.4)
expo-web-browser (13.0.3)


Configure project :react-native-reanimated
Android gradle plugin: 8.2.1
Gradle: 8.6


Task :app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets
warning: Bundler cache is empty, rebuilding (this may take a minute)
Writing bundle output to: android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle
Writing sourcemap output to: android\app\build\intermediates\sourcemaps\react\release\index.android.bundle.packager.map
Copying 33 asset files
Done writing bundle output
Done writing sourcemap output
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:763:63: warning: Direct call to eval(), but lexical scope is not supported.
...typeof expo === "undefined" ? eval("require") : function (moduleId) {
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:843:24: warning: the variable "URL" was not declared in function "_fetch"
props[0] = new URL(props[0], window.location?.origin).toString();
^~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:865:42: warning: the variable "fetch" was not declared in anonymous function " 22#"
value: wrapFetchWithWindowLocation(fetch)
^~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:1642:20: warning: the variable "Promise" was not declared in function "promiseMethodWrapper"
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
^~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:2021:18: warning: the variable "DebuggerInternal" was not declared in function "__shouldPauseOnThrow"
typeof DebuggerInternal !== 'undefined' &&
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:4644:5: warning: the variable "setImmediate" was not declared in function "handleResolved"
setImmediate(function () {
^~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:6116:9: warning: the variable "setTimeout" was not declared in anonymous function " 217#"
setTimeout(function () {
^~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:8996:5: warning: the variable "Headers" was not declared in anonymous function " 290#"
Headers,
^~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:8997:5: warning: the variable "Request" was not declared in anonymous function " 290#"
Request,
^~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:8998:5: warning: the variable "Response" was not declared in anonymous function " 290#"
Response
^~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:9155:24: warning: the variable "FileReader" was not declared in function "readBlobAsArrayBuffer"
var reader = new FileReader();
^~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:9206:36: warning: the variable "Blob" was not declared in anonymous function " 301#"
} else if (support.blob && Blob.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body)) {
^~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:9208:40: warning: the variable "FormData" was not declared in anonymous function " 301#"
} else if (support.formData && FormData.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body)) {
^~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:9210:44: warning: the variable "URLSearchParams" was not declared in anonymous function " 301#"
...e if (support.searchParams && URLSearchParams.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body...
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:9329:26: warning: the variable "AbortController" was not declared in anonymous function " 307#"
var ctrl = new AbortController();
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:9463:23: warning: the variable "XMLHttpRequest" was not declared in anonymous function " 311#"
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:9008:71: warning: the variable "self" was not declared in anonymous function " 293#"
...undefined' && globalThis || typeof self !== 'undefined' && self ||
^~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:20569:31: warning: the variable "nativeFabricUIManager" was not declared in anonymous function " 622#"
var _nativeFabricUIManage = nativeFabricUIManager,
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:20597:21: warning: the variable "clearTimeout" was not declared in anonymous function " 622#"
cancelTimeout = clearTimeout;
^~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:25227:30: warning: the variable "REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK" was not declared in anonymous function " 622#"
if ("undefined" !== typeof REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK) {
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:25342:27: warning: the variable "performance" was not declared in anonymous function " 653#"
if ("object" === typeof performance && "function" === typeof performance.no...
^~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:25365:26: warning: the variable "navigator" was not declared in anonymous function " 653#"
"undefined" !== typeof navigator && undefined !== navigator.scheduling && u...
^~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:25475:37: warning: the variable "MessageChannel" was not declared in anonymous function " 653#"
};else if ("undefined" !== typeof MessageChannel) {
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:25490:34: warning: the variable "nativeRuntimeScheduler" was not declared in anonymous function " 653#"
... = "undefined" !== typeof nativeRuntimeScheduler ? nativeRuntimeScheduler....
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:38801:34: warning: the variable "requestAnimationFrame" was not declared in function "start 9#"
...    this._animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(this.onUpdate.bind(this));
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:73801:11: warning: the variable "cancelAnimationFrame" was not declared in function "cleanup"
cancelAnimationFrame(this.splashScreenAnimationFrame);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:84611:100: warning: the variable "location" was not declared in function "registerSensor 1#"
...(0, _PlatformChecker.isWeb)() && location.protocol !== 'https:' ? ' Make s...
^~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:85877:26: warning: Direct call to eval(), but lexical scope is not supported.
workletFun = eval('(' + initData.code + '\n)');
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:85900:112: warning: the variable "_toString" was not declared in function "valueUnpacker"
...recognized by value unpacker: "${_toString(objectToUnpack)}".`);
^~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:86754:11: warning: the variable "queueMicrotask" was not declared in anonymous function " 2787#"
queueMicrotask(function () {
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:86880:33: warning: the variable "_WORKLET" was not declared in function "runOnJS"
if (SHOULD_BE_USE_WEB || !_WORKLET) {
^~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:103661:26: warning: the variable "structuredClone" was not declared in function "createAnimationWithExistingTransform"
newAnimationData = structuredClone(_config.AnimationsData[animationName]);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:103859:5: warning: the variable "document" was not declared in function "configureWebLayoutAnimations"
document.getElementById(PREDEFINED_WEB_ANIMATIONS_ID) !== null) {
^~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:103955:27: warning: the variable "HTMLElement" was not declared in function "findDescendantWithExitingAnimation"
if (!(node instanceof HTMLElement)) {
^~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:103981:24: warning: the variable "MutationObserver" was not declared in function "addHTMLMutationObserver"
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutationsList) {
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:104030:41: warning: the variable "getComputedStyle" was not declared in function "fixElementPosition"
...entBorderTopValue = parseInt(getComputedStyle(parent).borderTopWidth);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:108386:5: warning: the variable "jest" was not declared in function "beforeTest"
jest.useFakeTimers();
^~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:108922:26: warning: the variable "_getAnimationTimestamp" was not declared in function "computeEasingProgress"
var elapsedTime = (_getAnimationTimestamp() - startingTimestamp) / 1000;
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:152230:16: warning: the variable "SharedArrayBuffer" was not declared in function "from"
if (typeof SharedArrayBuffer !== 'undefined' && (isInstance(value, Shared...
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I have tried to build the project in expo I am getting this error.Please help me out

Start at the first reported error. Do you understand it? Can you fix it? Rebuild and tackle next one. If you cannot fix one error, then post that code and the error message, maybe we can help then

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
